# JSZip library, checking if zipfile is encrypted or not

Tags: javascript, jszip

Good day, I was wondering how can i check if the zip file is encrypted or not using JSZip library. I currently try to do a loadAsync function then if it goes to .catch() I always assume the reason for it is cause it is encrypted. I know there should be a better way to do this so I tried to check for the library itself then found entries having an isEncrypted() function being called. I just do not know how to access those entries. anyone knows how?

```
if (hasZipFileFlag === true) {
var jszip = new JSZip();
try {
    await jszip.loadAsync(testZip).then(function(res) {
      UtilLogClass.logFunc('ZIP READ SUCCESSFULLY', res);
    }).catch((err) => {
      UtilLogClass.logFunc('jszip loadAsync then() ERROR', err);
      zipFileHasPassFlag = true;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    UtilLogClass.logFunc('ZIP READ ERROR', err);
  }
}
```

※testZip is already a DOM object having a type of "application/x-zip-compressed" and I already have a way to determine if it is a zip file or not.

Answer (score 0):

From the `JSZip` [limitations docs](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/9fb481ac2a294f9c894226ea2992919d9d6a70aa/documentation/limitations.md), it looks like it's not possible:

> Not all features of zip files are supported. Classic zip files will work but encrypted zip, multi-volume, etc are not supported and the loadAsync() method will return a failed promise.

Edit (per comments):

You could refactor your code into something like this:

```js
if (hasZipFileFlag === true) {
  var jszip = new JSZip();
  try {
    const res = await jszip.loadAsync(testZip);
    UtilLogClass.logFunc("ZIP READ SUCCESSFULLY", res);
  } catch (err) {
    // if(err === "encrypted error from JSZip") { ... } 
    zipFileHasPassFlag = true;
    UtilLogClass.logFunc("ZIP READ ERROR", err);
  }
}
```

Any error thrown by the `loadAync(...)` method will be caught by the `catch` block.

Comment: I see,thanks for informing me. So is it safe to assume that what I am doing now is right?

Comment: You could remove the `.then(...)` and `.catch(...)` calls because you're using `await` and in a `try`/`catch` block. Sadly, I don't think there's a way to determine if an error is an "encryption" error or not without parsing the error string. Disclaimer: I've never used the `JSZip` library before.

Comment: I see,thanks for the help, so in the end i should pare the error into string? i tried doing it but didn't quite went well, any recommendations on how to do that?

Comment: I update the answer with a little more context to what I was getting at. Let me know if it's still not clear though.